# Grails: How to format date in language set in locale?

Tags: grails, gsp, date-formatting, formatdatetime

My multi-language Grails-based website has a switch for locale. I'd like to make sure date values are displayed in the locale set (and in the format currently being used in other outputs of scaffolding as the site is already available to the customer).
Here's an example code I'm using:

```
<g:formatDate date="${eventInstance?.date}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with following [this entry from the manual](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/formatDate.html) is:

```
<g:formatDate date="${eventInstance?.date}" formatName="default.date.format.short" />
```

and in my i18n/*.properties files settings for `default.date.format.short` (the global standard, `default.date.format`, was already set to another format).